# Does Safari on Windows support :before and :after pseudo elements?

Tags: css, windows, safari, cross-browser

Before and after CSS pseudo elements on windows Safari don't seem to be working.  Has anybody run into this issue before?  Is there a way I can enable this to work?  Is there any documentation where is bug is noted?  Thank you!

Comment: Are `::before` and `::after` not "working" either?

Answer (score 0):

I realized the pseudo elements were indeed being output but **Safari 5 does not support the background image shorthand**.  Using the individual background styles fixed my problem.